# Determinant is correct but wrong when I try and check it

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have to work out the determinant of the $(n \times n)$ matrix

$$A = \pmatrix{x & y & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\ 0 & x & y & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\ 0  & 0 & x & y &\cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 &0 &0 &0 & \cdots & y \\ y &0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x }$$

I worked it out and got the answer to be

$$\det(A) = x^n + (-1)^{n+1}y^n$$

which is right according to the answers, but when I check it, it's wrong. For example, if $n = 1$, then the determinant should be $x$ but we get

$$x^1 + (-1)^{1 + 1} y^1 = x + y.$$

Or if $n = 2$ then $\det(A) = x^2 - 0 \cdot y = x^2$, but putting it into the formula gives

$$x^2 + (-1)^{2+1}y^2 = x^2 - y^2.$$

Why is this happening?

Comment: $n=1$ is going to be rather a peculiar case, since it is not obvious how you could have a $1\times1$ determinant in that form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your matrix $A$ is not well-defined if $n=1$ because you are required to put $x$ in the upper left entry and $y$ in the lower left entry, which cannot be done simultaneously if $n=1$.

When $n=2$, your matrix is $A = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ y & x \end{pmatrix}$, which indeed has determinant $\det(A) = x^2 - y^2$.

Comment: For $n=2$ the matrix is ambiguously defined as there needs to be a $y$ to the right of the top-left $x$, but there also needs to be a $0$ in the top-right of the matrix. The OP assumed the version where a $0$ is in the top-right.

Comment: @DanielRust Bottom left you mean? Exactly how it is in the matrix I wrote?

Comment: @Michael Joyce how do you get that $y$ in the bottom left entry?

Comment: @DanielRust: True - my natural way of interpreting the patterns it that the location of the variables is indicated and then zeroes are to be filled in elsewhere.  But that is not the only interpretation possible.

Comment: @Kaish: In your pattern, you put a $y$ in the lower left entry of the matrix.  I assumed that had to be the case for all $n$.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Hang on, I think you're right. I think I miunderstood where the element $y$ in the bottom left goes in the matrix. EDIT: Yes, I get it now. Thank you :)

Comment: I suppose this really shows the shortcomings of ellipse notation when really each component $M_{ij}$ should be given a definition such as $M_{ij}=x$ if $i=j$, $M_{ij}=y$ if $j=i+1$ and $n\geq 2$, $M_{n,1}=y$ if $n\geq 2$ and $M_{ij}=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @DanielRust: I agree.  I think disallowing $n=1$ here is reasonable because the natural proof is to use the permutation definition of the determinant and recognize that there are exactly two non-zero contributions.  However, that is only true for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: That's a good point. As a general tip to the OP, if you find some strange 'incorrect cases' like this in the statement of a proposition which you think you've proved true, it's often a good idea to re-read your proof and see if the particular value of $n$ (or whatever is causing problems) you're looking at causes your reasoning in the proof to become flawed.